# Как убрать float?

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. Есть такой JSON:

```
{
  "cardPAN": 4916833222473083,
  "text3": "--",
  "text2": "--"
}
```

Если сделать `json_decode`, получится:
`["cardPAN"]=> float(4.91683322247E+15)`. Как можно перевести cardPAN в нормальный вид?

*P.S: Номер карты случайно генерированный.*

Comment: А чем вам float не угодил? Зачем его убирать? Это javascript, какая разница какой там тип. У вас есть какая-то проблема с этим номером дальше по ходу пьессы? Если да,озвучьте её, может стоит решать

Comment: По стандарту, тип числовых данных в JSON и так с плавающей точкой. Может, проблема только в формате вывода? Попробуйте `intval`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильнее всего будет перед отправкой преобразовывать `cardPAN` в строку.
Поскольку данное значение - это не номер, а набор знаков. И поскольку никакие арифметические операции над ним не планируются, то во избежание подобных конфликтов желательно обрабатывать его как строку.

Ну а чтобы буквально ответить на вопрос, то потребуется 64-битный РНР.
В 32-битной версии результат json_decode() по умолчанию всегда будет таким. Как показано в соседнем ответе, есть специальный флаг, который исправляет это поведение.

Comment: она 64-ех битная :)

Comment: Вам не кажется это решение слишком затратным и нескалируемым?

Answer (score 4):

Часто помогает чтение официальной документации:
http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php

> **options**
>   Битовая маска опций декодирования JSON. В настоящий момент поддерживается только `JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING` (по умолчанию большие целые числа приводятся к числам с плавающей запятой (float))

Далее эту строку можно преобразовать в BIGINT, если требуется.

Comment: Что-то вас редко видно. Я от скуки даже сообразил парсер на регулярках в каком-то ответе! Куда мир катится?

Comment: @VladD, я просматриваю в основном только одну метку [tag:регулярные-выражения], если вижу там хороший ответ, то просто плюсую его или предлагаю корректуру. Не ставлю целью ответить везде, а просто проверяю качество ответов. Ближайшие три месяца часто буду на сайте ввиду отпуска, а потом снова рабочие будни и точно просмотр только одной метки :)

Comment: О! Ну, в любом случае хорошего отпуска!